# How to get Id from custom email thread id of custom object?

Tags: case

We can use `Cases.getCaseIdFromEmailThreadId(String emailThreadId)` to get Case Id corresponding to the specified email thread id.

However, using apex, how can we get the record id of the custom object from the custom reference thread id?

Custom reference thread id another custom formula field obtained from:

`"ref:_" & LEFT($Organization.Id,5) & SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT($Organization.Id,11), "0", "" ) & "._" & LEFT(Id,5) & SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(Id,11), "0", "" ) & ":ref"`

'Email Thread ID is not valid' error is obtained even when trim the reference custom thread id in the proper format of _xxxxxxxxx._xxxxxxxxxx before supplying it to `getCaseIdFromEmailThreadId`.

Comment: There aren't email threads for any other object. Are you looking for information from an activity? Are you looking for something on a custom object record created when the case is created? Or via a custom email service?

Can you explain the process and include relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

I had almost similar requirement ,
How can I get the RefID(threadID) that SFDC add to the case subjects in email ?

we then used the below formula: 
[First 4 digits of the Organization ID followed by all digits after the last zero].[First 4 digits of the Case ID followed by all digits after the last zero]

For example (Not actual ID's): 
Organization ID = 00DX00000ased23 
Case ID = 00a40000000DDs2 
Thread ID = 00DXased23.00a4DDs2

The custom formula to generate RefId would look like this:

LEFT( $Organization.Id , 4) & IF (MID ( $Organization.Id, 5, 1) <> "0", RIGHT($Organization.Id, 11), IF (MID ( $Organization.Id, 6, 1) <> "0", RIGHT($Organization.Id, 10), IF (MID ( $Organization.Id, 7, 1) <> "0", RIGHT($Organization.Id, 9), IF (MID ( $Organization.Id, 8, 1) <> "0", RIGHT($Organization.Id, 8), IF (MID ( $Organization.Id, 9, 1) <> "0", RIGHT($Organization.Id, 7), IF (MID ( $Organization.Id, 10, 1) <> "0", RIGHT($Organization.Id, 6), IF (MID ( $Organization.Id, 11, 1) <> "0", RIGHT($Organization.Id, 5), IF (MID ( $Organization.Id, 12, 1) <> "0", RIGHT($Organization.Id, 4), IF (MID ( $Organization.Id, 13, 1) <> "0", RIGHT($Organization.Id, 3), IF (MID ( $Organization.Id, 14, 1) <> "0", RIGHT($Organization.Id, 2), "") ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) & "." & LEFT( Id, 4) & IF (MID ( Id, 5, 1) <> "0", RIGHT(Id, 11), IF (MID ( Id, 6, 1) <> "0", RIGHT(Id, 10), IF (MID ( Id, 7, 1) <> "0", RIGHT(Id, 9), IF (MID ( Id, 8, 1) <> "0", RIGHT(Id, 8), IF (MID ( Id, 9, 1) <> "0", RIGHT(Id, 7), IF (MID ( Id, 10, 1) <> "0", RIGHT(Id, 6), IF (MID ( Id, 11, 1) <> "0", RIGHT(Id, 5), IF (MID ( Id, 12, 1) <> "0", RIGHT(Id, 4), IF (MID ( Id, 13, 1) <> "0", RIGHT(Id, 3), IF (MID ( Id, 14, 1) <> "0", RIGHT(Id, 2), "") ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) )

---

So instead of the case object, try using your custom object ID.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Varun, thanks for taking the time. What I was trying to do is get record id from the thread id. For Case thread id, there is a standard class. However, for custom object thread id generated from custom formula, there is no standard method.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your question exactly.**
***You cannot reverse engineer a Case Id from the Thread Id***

Not with 100% accuracy everytime, due to the orignal substitution of the Zeros to form the Thread Id.
Hence you do not know where to put the zersos back into to remake the Case Id.
It would be guess work!

regarding the formulas provided
Personally I do not use varun guruvugari's formula. New Thread Ids can be generated with this:
"ref:*" & LEFT($Organization.Id,5) & SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(Organization.Id,10), "0", "" )& ".*" & LEFT(Id,5) & SUBSTITUTE(Left(RIGHT(Id,10), 5), "0", "") & RIGHT(Id,5) & ":ref"

This formula is not perfect and should be understood and tested regularly, incase Salesforce make changes.

Please refer this idea and upvote "expose the Thread_Id field"
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006trk